# Enforce www and trailing slash with mod_rewrite htaccess on a multi-domain site

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**My goal is to enforce www and a trailing slash on urls to achieve this, in a multi-domain environment:**

```
http://mydomain.com/company -> http://www.mydomain.com/company/
```

The catch is that certain sub domains must be excluded from the www prefix, yet still enforce the trailing slash, such as:

```
http://m.mydomain.com/company -> http://m.mydomain.com/company/
```

The additional factor is that I need to maintain any sub domain to avoid multiple redirects. For example:

```
http://dev.mydomain.com/login -> http://dev.mydomain.com/login/
```

Multiple redirects would result in:

```
http://dev.mydomain.com/login -> http://mydomain.com/login/
```

This needs to be avoided to keep the user on the current dev or mobile site.

**What I have so far:**

```
# Convert http://mydomain.com/company -> http://www.mydomain.com/company/
# Enforce www and trailing slash
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|dev|m)\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This works for a domain that is missing the www prefix and trailing slash and adds them both in 1 redirect.

```
# Convert http://mydomain.com/company/ -> http://www.mydomain.com/company/
# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|dev|m)\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works if a trailing slash is present and adds the www prefix if it is missing.

**What I cant figure out is a method of redirecting a user if a sub domain is present and the trailing slash is missing.**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^((.*/)?[^/\.]+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This rule works to add a trailing slash, but it will redirect a sub domain back to the root domain.

**Can you recommend a solution that combines these rules into as few options as possible, yet achieves my goals and avoids multiple redirects?**

Comment: Not programming related. Perhaps better ask http://webmasters.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com/

Comment: That might be a good suggestion, but there are many mod_rewrite questions here and since this is exclusive to the .htaccess file and not any server configuration I figured this was the best place to ask.

Comment: Seems like the issue of where to ask about mod_rewrite has been [asked before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6235/188688). I see a tendency towards server fault but no definite rule. So leave it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive, the pattern is matched against the file system path corresponding to the request. So either use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with a suitable variable, or use proper variables when building the replacement, to generate a URL instead of a path.

Have you tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$    [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^((.*/)?[^/\.]+)$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

That should be the formulation most in sync with your other two rules. You will have to add a condition to that, though.

Comment: Thank you. That actually works perfectly as the last set of rules to maintain the host. As soon as I stepped away from the computer I realized that what I needed to do. I'll leave this question open for a while to see if someone can cleverly combine any of the rules sets into something more compact and efficient.