# Mod-Rewrite/RewriteRule: Enforce https://www as protocol and domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I extracted the following code from a question here at stackoverflow ([Enforce www and trailing slash with mod_rewrite htaccess on a multi-domain site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866817/enforce-www-and-trailing-slash-with-mod-rewrite-htaccess-on-a-multi-domain-site)) and directly from [apache.org](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS).

The scenario consists of three requirements:

1. ensure, that the production domain starts always with www.
2. don't append www. to beta.domain.tld, dev.domain.tld, mobile.domain.tld
3. finally ensure, that every url gets rewritten to https.

I came up with the following conditions:

```
# Enforce www, if no subdomain is given
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(beta|dev|mobile|www)\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R]

# Enfore SSL for all Domains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

The mentioned rules works as expected, although **one single case doesn't work**:

https://domain.tld/ is not correctly redirected to https://www.domain.tld/

Can someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your 2 code with this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:beta|dev|mobile|www)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```